# apply topcoat to vertical installed face frames (doors were lacquer sprayed)

Tags: kitchens, refinishing

I have sanded/refinished kitchen cabinets & sprayed SW lacquer on doors. I can't spray faces because the boxes are installed and appliances nearby.  Can I apply the same Sherwin Williams lacquer using a brush or should i use polyurathane of similar sheen on the face frames?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* spray them it will just require masking things off.

As far as brushing the lacquer, read the can, it will tell you which methods of application are okay.